# Problems when adding dynamically to adder with gstreamer-0.10

Tags: gstreamer

I'm building a application for dub mp4 videos. My goal is while the user is watching a mp4 video, user can record his voice. Then my pipeline takes this audio file and add it into the pipeline adder element for listen all the records at the same time. After my goal is mix the audio and video into a mp4 file.
[image: Programs pipeline]

Well. My problem is when the recording is stopped and I add one file to the adder the pipeline crash. I do this:

1.- Pause the pipeline.

2.- Remove the "record bin" from the pipeline.

3.- Set state NULL to the "record bin"

4.- Send EOS event to the "record bin"

5.- Add the "audio bin"(adder) to the pipeline.

6.- Insert the needed silence to a wav file.

7.- Add audio file to the adder of "audio bin"  // Maybe, here is the problem.

My Vala/Genie code is here:

```
uses
    Gtk
    Gst
    Gee

class  AudioFilesSrc : Gst.Bin
    wavparse: Element
    src:Element
    audioconvert: Element
    srcpad: Pad
    sinkpad: Pad


def OnDynamicPad (element:Element, zz:Pad)
    var opad = audioconvert.get_static_pad("sink");
    zz.link(opad);

def open(p:Gst.Bin,mixer:Element,s1:string)
    src = Gst.ElementFactory.make("filesrc", "src1");
    wavparse = ElementFactory.make("wavparse","wavparse");
    audioconvert = ElementFactory.make("audioconvert","audioconvert");
    wavparse.pad_added.connect(OnDynamicPad);
    this.add_many(src,wavparse,audioconvert);
    src.link_many(wavparse,audioconvert);
    src.set("location",s1);
    // añade este bin a pipeline general
    p.add(this)
    //busca la salida de audioconvert1 y conviertela en la salida del bin
    srcpad = new Gst.GhostPad("src", audioconvert.get_static_pad("src"));
    this.add_pad(srcpad);
    print ".-.----------------------------- abierto "+s1
def conecta(mixer:Element)
    //crea una entrada al mixer
    sinkpad = mixer.get_request_pad("sink%d")
    //this.get_pad("src").link(this.sinkpad)
    srcpad.link(this.sinkpad)
    //this.srcpad.set_blocked(false)
    print ".-.----------------------------- conectado"

def close(p:Gst.Bin,mixer:Element)
    p.set_state(State.PAUSED)
    this.srcpad.set_blocked(true)
    this.set_state(State.NULL)
    this.srcpad.unlink(this.sinkpad)
    mixer.release_request_pad (this.sinkpad)


init
    Gtk.init (ref args)              
    Gst.init (ref args);
    var prueba = new ventana ()     
    prueba.show_all ()                
    Gtk.main ();                     

class ventana : Window            
    drawing_area:private DrawingArea;
    videopipeline: private Pipeline ;
    recordbin: Gst.Bin
    videobin: Gst.Bin
    audiobin: Gst.Bin

    volume: private Element ;
    videosrc :private Element;
    videosink: private Element;
    videodec: private Element;

    vaudiosink: private Element;
    vaudioparser: Element;
    vaudiodec: Element;
    vaudioadder: private Element;
    vaudioarchivos:list of AudioFilesSrc

    recordsrc :private Element;
    recordsink: private Element;
    recordconvert: private Element;
    recordencoder: private Element;

    comienzo_grabacion:float

    xid :private ulong ;
    reloj:uint
    position: float
    duracion:float
    bus:Gst.Bus
    bus2:Gst.Bus
    msg:Gst.Message
    msg2:Gst.Message
    seek_enabled:bool
    seek_enabled2:bool
    scale_1:Scale
    estado:string
    lugar:int
    numgrab:int=0
    archivos_audio:list of string
    button:Button
    button1:Button
    button2:Button
    button3:Button
    button4:Button
    button5:Button
    button6:Button
    button7:Button
    button8:Button
    init
        reloj = Timeout.add(1000, mover)
        title = "Bikoizketa"         
        default_height = 250               
        default_width = 450                
        window_position = WindowPosition.CENTER 
        comienzo_grabacion=-1

        // video pipeline
        duracion=Gst.CLOCK_TIME_NONE;
        this.videopipeline = new Pipeline ("mypipeline");

        videobin= new Gst.Bin("videobin")
        this.videosrc = ElementFactory.make ("filesrc", "filesrc2")
        this.videosrc.set("location","gontzal3.mp4");
        this.videodec = ElementFactory.make ("decodebin", "dec");
        this.videosink = ElementFactory.make ("xvimagesink", "videosink");
        this.videosink.set("force-aspect-ratio",true)
        this.videodec.pad_added.connect(OnDynamicPad);
        this.videobin.add_many (videosrc,videodec,videosink)
        this.videosrc.link_many (videodec,videosink)
        this.videopipeline.add(videobin)

        this.audiobin= new Gst.Bin("audiobin")
        this.vaudioadder = ElementFactory.make("adder","mixer");
        this.volume= ElementFactory.make("volume","volume");
        this.volume.set_property("volume",0.5)
        this.vaudiosink= ElementFactory.make("alsasink","alsasink");
        this.audiobin.add_many (vaudioadder,volume,vaudiosink)
        vaudioadder.link_many(volume,vaudiosink)
        this.videopipeline.add(audiobin)

        //añadiendo archivos
        vaudioarchivos=new list of AudioFilesSrc
        vaudioarchivos.add (new AudioFilesSrc())
        vaudioarchivos.last().open(audiobin,vaudioadder,"silencios.wav")
        vaudioarchivos.last().conecta(vaudioadder)
        numgrab++

        this.recordbin= new Gst.Bin("recorder")
        this.recordsrc= ElementFactory.make ("alsasrc","alsasrc")
        this.recordconvert=ElementFactory.make ("audioconvert","audioconvert")
        this.recordencoder = Gst.ElementFactory.make("wavenc", "encoder")
        this.recordsink= ElementFactory.make ("filesink","filesink")
        this.recordsink.set ("location","grabacionx.wav")
        this.recordbin.add_many (this.recordsrc,this.recordconvert, this.recordencoder, this.recordsink);
        this.recordsrc.link_many(this.recordconvert,recordencoder,recordsink)
        //videopipeline.add(recordbin)

        // creamos un boton con la siguiente etiqueta
        button = new Button.with_label ("grabar")
        button2 = new Button.with_label ("parar")
        button3 = new Button.with_label ("play")
        button4 = new Button.with_label ("pausar")
        var box= new Box (Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, 4)
        var box1= new Box (Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, 4)
        var box2= new Box (Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, 4)


        scale_1=  new Scale.with_range (Orientation.HORIZONTAL,0,1000,0.1)
        scale_1.value_changed.connect(on_scale)

        this.drawing_area = new DrawingArea ();
        this.drawing_area.realize.connect(on_realize);

        // Une el evento de clic de raton con la funcion pulsado
        button.clicked.connect (on_grabar)
        button2.clicked.connect (on_parar)
        button4.clicked.connect (on_pausa)
        button3.clicked.connect (on_play)
        // si pulsamos la x de la barra saldrá del loop
        destroy.connect(Gtk.main_quit)

        // añade el boton a la ventana
        this.add(box2)
        box.add(button3)
        box.add(button2)
        box.add(button4)
        box.add(button)

        box2.pack_start (drawing_area, true, true, 0);
        box2.pack_start (box,false, false, 0);
        box2.pack_start (scale_1,false, true, 0);

        estado="STOP"

        bus = this.videopipeline.get_bus()
        bus.add_signal_watch()
        msg = bus.timed_pop_filtered (10,Gst.MessageType.STATE_CHANGED | Gst.MessageType.ERROR | Gst.MessageType.EOS );
        bus.message.connect(on_msg)

    def on_msg(m:Gst.Message)
        if m.type== Gst.MessageType.STATE_CHANGED
            old_state:Gst.State;
            new_state:Gst.State;
            pending_state:Gst.State;
            m.parse_state_changed (out old_state, out new_state, out pending_state);
            if (m.src == this.videosink) 
                // Remember whether we are in the PLAYING state or not:
                if (new_state == Gst.State.PLAYING)
                    q : Gst.Query = new Gst.Query.seeking (Gst.Format.TIME);
                    start:int64;
                    end:int64;

                    if ( this.videosink.query (q) ) 
                        q.parse_seeking (null, out this.seek_enabled, out start, out end);
                        if seek_enabled 
                            pass

                if (new_state == Gst.State.READY)
                    //print "STOP"
                    pass
                if (new_state == Gst.State.PAUSED)
                    print "PAUSE"
                    q : Gst.Query = new Gst.Query.seeking (Gst.Format.TIME);
                    start:int64;
                    end:int64;

                    if ( this.videosink.query (q) ) 
                        q.parse_seeking (null, out this.seek_enabled, out start, out end);
                        if seek_enabled 
                            //print "enable cuando pause"+start.to_string()+"-"+end.to_string()
                            pass

    def on_scale( )//cuando la escala se mueve por el usuario

        if seek_enabled
            if this.videopipeline.seek_simple(Gst.Format.TIME,  SeekFlags.FLUSH| Gst.SeekFlags.ACCURATE, (int64)(scale_1.get_value()*Gst.SECOND))
                print "moviendo video"
        else
            print "video no se puede mover"

    def mover():bool // cambiando el valor mientras play el video.
        //desconectamos la deteccion de valores cambiados de la escala para evitar que el programa crea que el usuario esta cambiando el valor.
        scale_1.value_changed.disconnect(on_scale)
        var format = Gst.Format.TIME
        position=0
        if this.videopipeline.query_position(ref format, out position)
            scale_1.set_value(position/Gst.MSECOND/1000)
        duracion=0;
        if this.videopipeline.query_duration(ref format, out duracion)
            duracion=duracion/Gst.MSECOND/1000
            if estado!="STOP" do scale_1.set_range(0,duracion)
        scale_1.value_changed.connect(on_scale)
        return true

    def on_realize()
        this.xid = (ulong)Gdk.X11Window.get_xid(this.drawing_area.get_window());

    def on_grabar (btn : Button)
        if estado=="STOP" or estado=="PAUSA"
            recordsink.set("location","grabacion"+(numgrab).to_string()+".wav")
            this.videopipeline.add(this.recordbin)
            this.videopipeline.remove(audiobin)
            print "grabando"
            button.set_label("parar")
            var xoverlay = this.videosink as XOverlay;
            xoverlay.set_xwindow_id (this.xid);

            this.videopipeline.set_state (State.PLAYING);
            estado="REC"
            var format = Gst.Format.TIME
            position: int64
            if this.videopipeline.query_position(ref format, out position)
                comienzo_grabacion=(position/Gst.MSECOND/1000)
            else
                comienzo_grabacion=-1
        else if estado=="REC"
            //parando la grabación
            estado="PLAY"
            button.set_label("grabar")
            videopipeline.set_state(State.PAUSED)
            this.videopipeline.remove(recordbin)
            this.recordbin.set_state(State.NULL)
            this.recordbin.send_event(new Event.eos())
            this.videopipeline.add(audiobin)
            this.on_insertar()


    def on_insertar()
        if comienzo_grabacion!=-1
            try
                Process.spawn_command_line_sync ("sox grabacion"+numgrab.to_string()+".wav grabacion_x.wav pad "+((int64)comienzo_grabacion).to_string()+"@0")
                Process.spawn_command_line_sync ("mv grabacion_x.wav grabacion"+numgrab.to_string()+".wav")
                pass
            except
                pass

        print "grabacion a añadir :"+numgrab.to_string()
        vaudioarchivos.add((new AudioFilesSrc()))
        vaudioarchivos.last().open(this.audiobin,this.vaudioadder,"grabacion"+numgrab.to_string()+".wav")
        vaudioarchivos.last().conecta(this.vaudioadder)
        numgrab+=1

    def on_pausa (btn:Button)
        if estado=="PLAY" 
            print "pausando"
            this.videopipeline.set_state (State.PAUSED);
            estado="PAUSA"

    def on_parar (btn : Button)
        if estado=="PLAY" or estado=="PAUSA"
            var xoverlay = this.videosink as XOverlay;
            xoverlay.set_xwindow_id (this.xid);
            this.videopipeline.set_state (State.READY);
            this.scale_1.set_value(0)
            estado="STOP"

    def on_play (btn : Button)
        if estado=="STOP" or estado=="PAUSA"
            print "tocando"
            var xoverlay = this.videosink as XOverlay;
            xoverlay.set_xwindow_id (this.xid);

            this.videopipeline.set_state (State.PLAYING);
            estado="PLAY"

    def OnDynamicPad (element:Element, zz:Pad)
        var opad = this.videosink.get_static_pad("sink");
        zz.link(opad);
```

Comment: Kaixo! Is there any reason you are using gstreamer 0.1 and not gstreamer 1.0? If I compile your code with gstreamer 1.0 (and some small modifications) it runs and produces audio files without crashing. Do you get any output in the terminal when it crashes?

Comment: Kaixo!!! :->
The only reason is the Windows bundle by Tarnyko for crosscompiling. But is not problem if I use 1.0. Yes, it produces audiofiles but can you listen them all together?. No output yet.

Comment: I have tryed using 1.0 and I get this output error while running def conecta:
GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_pad_link_full: assertion 'GST_IS_PAD (sinkpad)' failed
And after when playing: gtk_range_set_range: assertion 'min <= max' failed

Answer (score 0):

I have made some minor modifications to your code and compiled it with gstreamer-1.0 using the following build command:

```
valac --pkg gdk-x11-3.0 --pkg gstreamer-1.0 --pkg gstreamer-video-1.0 --pkg gee-0.8 --pkg gtk+-3.0 bikoizketa.gs
```

If I click on the "grabar" button, the video plays and I can record myself speaking. When I click the same button (now "parar") it saves that recording to a file called grabacion1.wav which plays fine but is only the recording from my microphone.

The modifications I have made have been principally to update it to the gstreamer 1.0 API and to the new GDK X11 API. I also added a check for negative values for the Scale (line 254) because the stream in the recording state returns -1 (presumably because the stream duration is potentially infinite).

I also noticed that there were `pass` statements in your try-catch clause which was preventing it from throwing an error. With these removed, I get the following error if I record something, hit the "pausar" button and then record again:

`sox WARN wav: Premature EOF on .wav input file`

```
[indent=4]

uses
    Gtk
    Gst
    Gee

class  AudioFilesSrc : Gst.Bin
    wavparse: Element
    src: Element
    audioconvert: Element
    srcpad: Pad
    sinkpad: Pad


    def OnDynamicPad (element:Element, zz:Pad)
        var opad = audioconvert.get_static_pad("sink");
        zz.link(opad);

    def open(p:Gst.Bin,mixer:Element,s1:string)
        src = Gst.ElementFactory.make("filesrc", "src1");
        wavparse = ElementFactory.make("wavparse","wavparse");
        audioconvert = ElementFactory.make("audioconvert","audioconvert");
        wavparse.pad_added.connect(OnDynamicPad);
        this.add_many(src,wavparse,audioconvert);
        src.link_many(wavparse,audioconvert);
        src.set("location",s1);
        // añade este bin a pipeline general
        p.add(this)
        //busca la salida de audioconvert1 y conviertela en la salida del bin
        srcpad = new Gst.GhostPad("src", audioconvert.get_static_pad("src"));
        this.add_pad(srcpad);
        print ".-.----------------------------- abierto "+s1

    def conecta(mixer:Element)
        //crea una entrada al mixer
        sinkpad = mixer.get_request_pad("sink_%u")
        //this.get_pad("src").link(this.sinkpad)
        srcpad.link(this.sinkpad)
        //this.srcpad.set_blocked(false)
        print ".-.----------------------------- conectado"

    def close(p:Gst.Bin,mixer:Element)
        p.set_state(State.PAUSED)
        //this.srcpad.set_blocked(true)
        this.srcpad.add_probe(PadProbeType.BLOCK, cb)
        this.set_state(State.NULL)
        this.srcpad.unlink(this.sinkpad)
        mixer.release_request_pad (this.sinkpad)

    def cb (p:Pad, info:PadProbeInfo) : PadProbeReturn
        return PadProbeReturn.OK

init
    Gtk.init (ref args)              
    Gst.init (ref args);
    var prueba = new ventana ()     
    prueba.show_all ()                
    Gtk.main ();                     

class ventana : Window            
    drawing_area:private DrawingArea;
    videopipeline: private Pipeline ;
    recordbin: Gst.Bin
    videobin: Gst.Bin
    audiobin: Gst.Bin

    volume: private Element ;
    videosrc :private Element;
    videosink: private Element;
    videodec: private Element;

    vaudiosink: private Element;
    vaudioparser: Element;
    vaudiodec: Element;
    vaudioadder: private Element;
    vaudioarchivos:list of AudioFilesSrc

    recordsrc :private Element;
    recordsink: private Element;
    recordconvert: private Element;
    recordencoder: private Element;

    comienzo_grabacion:float

    xid :private ulong ;
    reloj:uint
    position: float
    duracion:float
    bus:Gst.Bus
    bus2:Gst.Bus
    msg:Gst.Message
    msg2:Gst.Message
    seek_enabled:bool
    seek_enabled2:bool
    scale_1:Scale
    estado:string
    lugar:int
    numgrab:int=0
    archivos_audio:list of string
    button:Button
    button1:Button
    button2:Button
    button3:Button
    button4:Button
    button5:Button
    button6:Button
    button7:Button
    button8:Button
    init
        reloj = Timeout.add(1000, mover)
        title = "Bikoizketa"         
        default_height = 250               
        default_width = 450                
        window_position = WindowPosition.CENTER 
        comienzo_grabacion=-1

        // video pipeline
        duracion=Gst.CLOCK_TIME_NONE;
        this.videopipeline = new Pipeline ("mypipeline");

        videobin= new Gst.Bin("videobin")
        this.videosrc = ElementFactory.make ("filesrc", "filesrc2")
        this.videosrc.set("location","gontzal3.mp4");
        this.videodec = ElementFactory.make ("decodebin", "dec");
        this.videosink = ElementFactory.make ("xvimagesink", "videosink");
        this.videosink.set("force-aspect-ratio",true)
        this.videodec.pad_added.connect(OnDynamicPad);
        this.videobin.add_many (videosrc,videodec,videosink)
        this.videosrc.link_many (videodec,videosink)
        this.videopipeline.add(videobin)

        this.audiobin= new Gst.Bin("audiobin")
        this.vaudioadder = ElementFactory.make("adder","mixer");
        this.volume= ElementFactory.make("volume","volume");
        this.volume.set_property("volume",0.5)
        // creamos un elemento de autoaudiosink (en lugar de alsaaudiosink)
        this.vaudiosink= ElementFactory.make("autoaudiosink","autoaudiosink");
        this.audiobin.add_many (vaudioadder,volume,vaudiosink)
        vaudioadder.link_many(volume,vaudiosink)
        this.videopipeline.add(audiobin)

        //añadiendo archivos
        vaudioarchivos=new list of AudioFilesSrc
        vaudioarchivos.add (new AudioFilesSrc())
        vaudioarchivos.last().open(audiobin,vaudioadder,"silencio.wav")
        vaudioarchivos.last().conecta(vaudioadder)
        numgrab++

        this.recordbin= new Gst.Bin("recorder")
        // creamos un elemento de autoaudiosrc (en lugar de alsaaudiosrc)
        this.recordsrc= ElementFactory.make ("autoaudiosrc","autoaudiosrc")
        this.recordconvert=ElementFactory.make ("audioconvert","audioconvert")
        this.recordencoder = Gst.ElementFactory.make("wavenc", "encoder")
        this.recordsink= ElementFactory.make ("filesink","filesink")
        this.recordsink.set ("location","file.wav")

        this.recordbin.add_many (this.recordsrc,this.recordconvert, this.recordencoder, this.recordsink);
        this.recordsrc.link_many(this.recordconvert,recordencoder,recordsink)
        //videopipeline.add(recordbin)

        // creamos un boton con la siguiente etiqueta
        button = new Button.with_label ("grabar")
        button2 = new Button.with_label ("parar")
        button3 = new Button.with_label ("play")
        button4 = new Button.with_label ("pausar")
        var box= new Box (Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, 4)
        var box1= new Box (Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, 4)
        var box2= new Box (Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, 4)


        scale_1=  new Scale.with_range (Orientation.HORIZONTAL,0,1000,0.1)
        scale_1.value_changed.connect(on_scale)

        this.drawing_area = new DrawingArea ();
        this.drawing_area.realize.connect(on_realize);

        // Une el evento de clic de raton con la funcion pulsado
        button.clicked.connect (on_grabar)
        button2.clicked.connect (on_parar)
        button4.clicked.connect (on_pausa)
        button3.clicked.connect (on_play)
        // si pulsamos la x de la barra saldrá del loop
        destroy.connect(Gtk.main_quit)

        // añade el boton a la ventana
        this.add(box2)
        box.add(button3)
        box.add(button2)
        box.add(button4)
        box.add(button)

        box2.pack_start (drawing_area, true, true, 0);
        box2.pack_start (box,false, false, 0);
        box2.pack_start (scale_1,false, true, 0);

        estado="STOP"

        bus = this.videopipeline.get_bus()
        bus.add_signal_watch()
        msg = bus.timed_pop_filtered (10,Gst.MessageType.STATE_CHANGED | Gst.MessageType.ERROR | Gst.MessageType.EOS );
        bus.message.connect(on_msg)

    def on_msg(m:Gst.Message)
        if m.type== Gst.MessageType.STATE_CHANGED
            old_state:Gst.State;
            new_state:Gst.State;
            pending_state:Gst.State;
            m.parse_state_changed (out old_state, out new_state, out pending_state);
            if (m.src == this.videosink) 
                // Remember whether we are in the PLAYING state or not:
                if (new_state == Gst.State.PLAYING)
                    q : Gst.Query = new Gst.Query.seeking (Gst.Format.TIME);
                    start:int64;
                    end:int64;

                    if ( this.videosink.query (q) ) 
                        q.parse_seeking (null, out this.seek_enabled, out start, out end);
                        if seek_enabled 
                            pass

                if (new_state == Gst.State.READY)
                    //print "STOP"
                    pass
                if (new_state == Gst.State.PAUSED)
                    print "PAUSE"
                    q : Gst.Query = new Gst.Query.seeking (Gst.Format.TIME);
                    start:int64;
                    end:int64;

                    if ( this.videosink.query (q) ) 
                        q.parse_seeking (null, out this.seek_enabled, out start, out end);
                        if seek_enabled 
                            //print "enable cuando pause"+start.to_string()+"-"+end.to_string()
                            pass

    def on_scale( )//cuando la escala se mueve por el usuario

        if seek_enabled
            if this.videopipeline.seek_simple(Gst.Format.TIME,  SeekFlags.FLUSH| Gst.SeekFlags.ACCURATE, (int64)(scale_1.get_value()*Gst.SECOND))
                print "moviendo video"
        else
            print "video no se puede mover"

    def mover():bool // cambiando el valor mientras play el video.
        //desconectamos la deteccion de valores cambiados de la escala para evitar que el programa crea que el usuario esta cambiando el valor.
        scale_1.value_changed.disconnect(on_scale)
        var format = Gst.Format.TIME
        position=0
        if this.videopipeline.query_position(format, out position)
            scale_1.set_value(position/Gst.MSECOND/1000)
        duracion=0;
        if this.videopipeline.query_duration(format, out duracion)
            duracion=duracion >= 0 ? duracion/Gst.MSECOND/1000 : 0
            if estado!="STOP" do scale_1.set_range(0,duracion)
        scale_1.value_changed.connect(on_scale)
        return true

    def on_realize()
        this.xid = (ulong)((Gdk.X11.Window)this.drawing_area.get_window()).get_xid();

    def on_grabar (btn : Button)
        if estado=="STOP" or estado=="PAUSA"
            recordsink.set("location","grabacion"+(numgrab).to_string()+".wav")
            this.videopipeline.add(this.recordbin)
            this.videopipeline.remove(audiobin)
            print "grabando"
            button.set_label("parar")
            var xoverlay = this.videosink as Video.Overlay
            xoverlay.set_window_handle ((uint*)this.xid);

            this.videopipeline.set_state (State.PLAYING);
            estado="REC"
            var format = Gst.Format.TIME
            position: int64
            if this.videopipeline.query_position(format, out position)
                comienzo_grabacion=(position/Gst.MSECOND/1000)
            else
                comienzo_grabacion=-1
        else if estado=="REC"
            //parando la grabación
            estado="PLAY"
            button.set_label("grabar")
            videopipeline.set_state(State.PAUSED)
            this.videopipeline.remove(recordbin)
            this.recordbin.set_state(State.NULL)
            this.recordbin.send_event(new Event.eos())
            this.videopipeline.add(audiobin)
            this.on_insertar()


    def on_insertar()
        if comienzo_grabacion!=-1
            try
                Process.spawn_command_line_sync ("sox grabacion"+numgrab.to_string()+".wav grabacion_x.wav pad "+((int64)comienzo_grabacion).to_string()+"@0")
                Process.spawn_command_line_sync ("mv grabacion_x.wav grabacion"+numgrab.to_string()+".wav")
            except err:Error
                print err.message

        print "grabacion a añadir :"+numgrab.to_string()
        vaudioarchivos.add((new AudioFilesSrc()))
        vaudioarchivos.last().open(this.audiobin,this.vaudioadder,"grabacion"+numgrab.to_string()+".wav")
        vaudioarchivos.last().conecta(this.vaudioadder)
        numgrab+=1

    def on_pausa (btn:Button)
        if estado=="PLAY" 
            print "pausando"
            this.videopipeline.set_state (State.PAUSED);
            estado="PAUSA"

    def on_parar (btn : Button)
        if estado=="PLAY" or estado=="PAUSA"
            var xoverlay = this.videosink as Video.Overlay
            xoverlay.set_window_handle ((uint*)this.xid);
            this.videopipeline.set_state (State.READY);
            this.scale_1.set_value(0)
            estado="STOP"

    def on_play (btn : Button)
        if estado=="STOP" or estado=="PAUSA"
            print "tocando"
            var xoverlay = this.videosink as Video.Overlay
            xoverlay.set_window_handle ((uint*)this.xid);

            this.videopipeline.set_state (State.PLAYING);
            estado="PLAY"

    def OnDynamicPad (element:Element, zz:Pad)
        var opad = this.videosink.get_static_pad("sink");
        zz.link(opad);
```

If I understand correctly you ultimately want to record the person speaking every time they press "grabar" and save that to a sequence of files grabacion1.wav, grabacion2.wav etc and when they have finished to combine them with the video and save the output to a file? If so, I don't quite see where that last bit is supposed to occur.

Comment: Yes, you have correctly explained. The recorder saves rigth. But I can't control the adder element.